# Confirm if apps have successfully installed from Google Play (Without looking at the phone)

Tags: google-play-store

My girlfriend recently had her phone stolen and I'm trying to track it down by remotely installing apps on her phone via Google Play, but I can't tell if the apps are successfully installed.  For example, if I turn off my phone completely, and install an app on it from Google Play, it will still report "installed" even though my phone's turned off.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your specific question is, unlikely.  You can install an app that has an interface that you can communicate with.  Communicating with that interface can allow you to know.  But other than that, it's unlikely.  And you'd have to have confirmation on the android to accept the manifest of the app's requirement list.

You may not be fully lost, however,  Google does have a feature by default that you might be able to **track your phone even if you didn't install an app**.

These are some requirement which most people normally have:

```
- The android is connected with your Google account.
- Your android has access to the internet.
- The the Android Device Manager (ADM) to locate your android (turned off by default)
- Allowed ADM to lock your android and erase its data (turned off by default).
```

Try Google's [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager).

Answer (score 0):

I won't answer the question itself, but the general question on how to find the stolen phone, and for sure the way you trying is not going to get you anywhere. In order to have a chance to find the stolen phone you should have already install any anti theft app like Google's Android Manager or Cerberus or any similar app. Of course these apps will work only if the thief has not already uninstalled them or reset the phone and installed a new ROM.

Comment: So is there a way to check, what are dead ends? Because the phone will ring for a while... but then shortly they turn it off after we try to call it.

Comment: I've been trying to install android lost and then text it "androidlost register" ...but that seems to not be working... even though it says it's "installed"

Answer (score 0):

Go to google play on a computer and try to install an app. After pushing the Install/Installed button a popup will appear listing the permissions it requires and below that a drop down listing the devices you can install it on. Click on the drop down. If it is currently installed it will say "Your device already has this item installed" next to the device name. Otherwise it will say the last time the device was used.

I just tested this by installing an app and canceling it in the middle of the install, then re-installing it, then uninstalling it.